# Reference request: table of representation rings and relations

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, lie-groups

Where can one find a table of generator–relator expressions for representation rings $R(G)$ of simple Lie groups $G$ and explicit maps between them? For example, given a maximal torus $T < G$ or a cover $\tilde G \to G$, I'd like this hypothetical table to have descriptions of the induced $$R(G) \rightarrowtail R(T),$$
$$R(G) \to R(\tilde G)$$ in terms of where they take generators. In principle, one could do this for oneself, but surely it's already written down somewhere.

**edit**: I'm aware that $R(T)$ is a Laurent polynomial ring, that $R(G) \cong R(T)^W$, and that $R(G)$ is a polynomial ring if $\pi_1 G$ is torsion-free or $G = \mathrm{SO}(2n+1)$, know what this implies for simply-connected classical groups, and know references to papers giving expressions for simply-connected exceptional groups. What I'm interested in is explicit descriptions for non–simply-connected groups in terms of their maximal tori and indications of where generators go under homomorphisms (including covering maps).

Comment: May be I missed something, but isn't this equivalent to A) having character formulas for the irreducible reps of $G$, B) formulas for how a tensor product of two irreducible reps splits into a direct sum of irreducibles, and C) knowing which cosets of the root lattice are available as weights for non-simply-connected groups?

Comment: I guess it is the same as that, just more compact. Do you have a reference that has all that information?

Comment: I think "Representations of Compact Lie Groups" by tom Dieck and Bröcker has some examples.

Comment: It definitely has some. I'd looked through it before asking the questions but I'm hoping for something more thorough.